# JetBrains ToolBox 'connection refused' - what URLs to whitelist on proxy?

Tags: proxy, jetbrains-toolbox

I'm behind a corporate proxy with extremely restrictive settings. I'm trying to use JetBrains ToolBox, but I keep getting "connection refused" when trying to log in.

What URLs (except for `*.jetbrains.com/*`) do I need to whitelist on the proxy in order to be able to use the ToolBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern should be enough now. If not, please file an issue to the tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newissue?project=ALL&clearDraft=true